# PWA Service Worker In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I'm trying to run service worker on my react app. So I used the tutorial and installed a react app with pwa-template, and changed the unregister part to register in my index.js. I'm not sure what to do next cause it's not working and I guess I missed something in between. Can anyone help me with that?

ps: this is my github repository for my project. I mixed it with pwas and I've done all parts. Note that you need to clone and run this api with "npm run prod" to work with my code.

my code repository:
https://github.com/Sararmjalal/blogtorpwa

api code repository:
https://github.com/Sararmjalal/blogtorpwa

I've done everything but still service worker not registering. can you check out what I did wrong?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need  to install third-party packages for working with `PWAs` .
follow instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71158834/how-to-make-an-existing-react-app-installable-pwa) link.

Comment: So one question, how can I do "Copy over everything with "workbox" from the package.json file." ?

Comment: it means you have to rewrite `npm scripts`that has workbox at the beginning from `cra-template-pwa`, to your existing project . also keep in the mind that `PWAs`sare created on build , so you have to run custom build command with `workbox` or using `npm run build` on `cra-template-pwa`

Comment: checkout my question again. I've edited it with the link to my src code. I've done everything you told me and still not working!